# How to use translation string with parameter in blade? (Laravel 5.8)

Tags: laravel, localization, laravel-blade, laravel-5.8

I have a translation string inside lang/tr/setting like this:

```
'permits' => [
    'halfdaynote' => 'Çalışmış sayılacağı süreler toplam :hours saat olmalıdır.',
],
```

I know that I can use this string in backend code like in a Controller this way and it's fine:

```
__('setting.permits.halfdaynote', ['hours', '7,5'])
```

When it comes to blade I have tried all of the following and all failed:

```
@lang('setting.permits.halfdaynote', ['hours', '7,5'])

{{ __('setting.permits.halfdaynote', ['hours', '7,5']) }}

{!! __('setting.permits.halfdaynote', ['hours', '7,5']) !!}

<?= __('setting.permits.halfdaynote', ['hours', '7,5']) ?>

<?php echo __('setting.permits.halfdaynote', ['hours', '7,5']) ?>
```

The result looks like this:

> Not: Çalışmış sayılacağı süreler toplam :hours saat olmalıdır.

Where it must be like this:

> Not: Çalışmış sayılacağı süreler toplam 7,5 saat olmalıdır.

Is there any way to make this work?

Comment: Did you try to put your translation in a json file? "resources/lang/en.json"

Comment: You can not use dot in translation string. dot represents array. Try changin dot to -, # or something

Comment: @mchev Why would I do that? Laravel already has a localization system, I would like to use that.

Comment: @Ts8060 You can.

Comment: @AdemTepe according to the doc, this is a way "Or, translation strings may be defined within JSON files that are placed within the resources/lang directory"

Comment: Hi @AdemTepe what exactly doesn't work?

The replacemnt array should be written like this `{{ __('setting.permits.halfdaynote', ['hours' => '7,5']) }}`

Comment: @mchev Ok, I'm going to check that but the question remains for that way too.

Comment: @Froxz I have edited the question to show that.

Comment: @AdemTepe read my above reply change `,` to `=>`

Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/localization#replacing-parameters-in-translation-strings

Comment: @Froxz Ohh damn!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix your issue you need to specify your parameters as `key => value` pair:

```php
{{ __('setting.permits.halfdaynote', ['hours' => '7,5']) }}
```

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/localization#replacing-parameters-in-translation-strings)

Comment: I wish they put this feature also in @lang directive.

Comment: @AdemTepe it does work. (at least should be try it)

Comment: Wow, it really does! I cleared everything to be sure (cache, view, Ctrl + F5) to be sure. Thank you so much. The reason I didn't expect that was PhpStorm shows that @lang() method signature has one parameter only.